# Remove date, time and file extension with sed

Tags: sed

**Introduction**

Hi! I've scanning bunch of domain for it's subdomain. The result; is a json file along with time & date with _ separator.

```
521wei.xin_2022_04_03_13_09_20.json             wechat.design_2022_04_02_15_13_13.json                                     wechat.org_2022_04_01_15_47_58.json                       admin.wechat.com_2022_04_01_15_37_35.json       wechatapp.com_2022_04_01_16_38_38.json
api.weixin.qq.com_2022_04_01_15_55_38.json      wechatlegal.cn_2022_04_01_16_20_20.json
```

The intention is to extract the domain names and decimate the rest of it (Date, Time, and File Extension)

**Problematic**

I've trying to use `sed` regex to identify the timestamp.

```
''/_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}.json/d''
```

But it does nothing. Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you the following sed command to strip out the timestamps and extension from the filename:

```
sed -e 's/[0-9_]\+.json/ /gm'
```

[image]

###### Sample usage:

```bash
echo "521wei.xin_2022_04_03_13_09_20.json \
wechat.design_2022_04_02_15_13_13.json \
wechat.org_2022_04_01_15_47_58.json \
admin.wechat.com_2022_04_01_15_37_35.json \
wechatapp.com_2022_04_01_16_38_38.json \
api.weixin.qq.com_2022_04_01_15_55_38.json \
wechatlegal.cn_2022_04_01_16_20_20.json" | sed -e 's/[0-9_]\+.json/ /gm'
```

###### Output

```bash
521wei.xin  wechat.design  wechat.org  admin.wechat.com  wechatapp.com  api.weixin.qq.com  wechatlegal.cn
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGeqAQ/1)

Answer (score 1):

Can Achieve similar result from the first answer with `cut` command:

```
cut -d '_' -f '1' listWechat.txt
```